# How to send email to specific cell onedit trigger for another specific cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to create a script for a Google Spreadsheet which sends an email to the address in a specific row and column when another specific cell is that row is edited. E.G. cell E5 is edited so an email is sent to the address in B5; cell E6 is edited so an email is sent to address in B6, etc

Right now I have the following code (edited out URL), but it sends to the email address in column B whenever any cell is edited, not the specific cell:

```
  function Sheet1() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
   var sheet = s.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
   var numRows = 1000;   // Number of rows to process
   var data = sheet.getSheetValues(startRow,1,numRows,1000) // (startrow, startcolumn, #rows, #columns)

 // var data = dataRange.getValues();

   Logger.log(data);
   for (var i=0;i<numRows; i++) {

  var email = data[i][1]; //1st column is preferred email (note count begins from 0)
  var accountsNotes = data[i][5];// 5th column is team notes
  var subject4TCemail = "[Alert] Your escalation has been updated";
  var body4TCemail = "Be Calm and Carry on... Also please check the escalation form here";

  //var changedcellvalue=e.value;
//  var returnedrange=e.range;

//  Logger.log(changedcellvalue);
      if (email!="") {
         GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject4email,body4email);
  };

  }}
```

How would you recommend editing this to only send when its a cell in a specific column to an address in that specific row? Thanks!